# pulling a dictionary out of the function that created it (python)

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I am importing a list from an outside document, and inputing that list into a dictionary. This question is applicable to pretty much all values associated to a variable from inside a function. Once the function is complete how do I pull that information from the function with out having to assign the variables as global. Sorry if this question isnt very clear, im having trouble vocalizing it.

Here is the program so far. the dictionary 'result' has values while in the function but when I try to call it from outside the function its empty.

```
fin = open('words.txt')

def dictionary(words):
   result = {}
   for line in words:
      result[line] = 'yupp!' # dont care about value at the moment
   return result

word_dict = dictionary(fin)
'the' in word_dict# checking to see if a word is in the dictionary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
result = dictionary(fin)
```

to assign the value returned by `dictionary` to the variable `result`.

Note that `result` is a global variable, so I'm not sure what you mean by "with
   out having to assign the variables as global".

---

```
def dictionary(words):
    result = {}
    for word in words:
        word = word.strip()
        result[word] = 'yupp!'
    return result

with open('words.txt') as fin:
    result = dictionary(fin)
    print('the' in result)
```

---

Alternatively,

```
def dictionary(words):
    return dict.fromkeys((word.strip() for word in words), 'yupp')
```

Comment: *lightbulb* I knew I was missing a key thing. I've made the changes you suggested yet when I check to see if a value is in my dictionary it returns nothing at all. Not a True or False.

Comment: It probably is due to `line` ending with a `\n`. Try `line = line.strip()`. I've added some code to show what I mean.

Comment: That was EXACTLY it. at first I was trying to do  `line.strip()` with out assigning it to anything. when I place your `line = line.strip()` it worked marvelously! I need to really figure out when I need to assign something to a value and when I dont. Like with the `a.strip()` needs to be assigned to something, whereas `sorted(list)` doesnt.

Comment: Strings are immutable. So any method you call on a string can not mutate the string itself. It must return a new string. Hence, `line = line.strip()` is needed. A list is mutable. Generally speaking, when you call a method of a mutable object, it mutates the object and returns `None`. For example, `list.sort()` mutates `list` and returns `None`. In contrast, the function `sorted` does not mutate `list`, and returns a new sorted list. So you would need `list = sorted(list)` if you wanted to mutate `list`. But you would never write that, since `list.sort()` suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the result of the function to a variable:

```
result = dictionary(fin) # note that this variable does not need to be named 'result'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cleaner way, using a generator expression over the dict constructor and using context handlers to manage opening/closing the file handle.

```
>>> def dictionary(fname='/usr/share/dict/words'):
...   with open(fname) as words:
...     return dict((word.strip(), 'yupp!') for word in words)
... 
>>> my_dictionary = dictionary()
>>> 'the' in my_dictionary
True
>>> my_dictionary['the']
'yupp!'
```

Comment: So I got it to return False when checking for a key. Couldnt figure out why everything was returning false. so I printed the entire dictionary and every word has '\n'. I need to strip that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Your code worked perfectly! I wrote my comment in the wrong box.